# Running Meteor npm packages depending if it's running on Windows or Linux (raspi)?

Tags: windows, meteor, npm, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a Meteor App will be running on a Raspberry Pi using [Wiring-Pi](https://github.com/eugeneware/wiring-pi) that's deployed with npm. I'm currently developing it on Windows 7/8 and have a git branch for the Pi.

On the Pi, it's able to use meteorhacks:npm and build Wiring-Pi without issues.
On Windows, it has problems when it looks for and tries to install the wiring-Pi dependencies, which makes sense..

**Is there a way to have meteor detect the platform and when it's running on the PI it includes npm and wiring-pi, and on Windows it doesn't?**

Is this something I need to bring up with the wiring-pi devs? 
Part of the output from the console:

> - npm ERR! Failed at the wiring-pi@2.0.0 install script '/bin/bash./install.sh'.
> - npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the wiring-pi package,
> - npm ERR! not with npm itself.

Should I just maintain what I'm doing with a separate Pi branch?

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: I think you might find help here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a look. Though, it does seem that this question doesn't only pertain to the Raspberry Pi, but if I had other modules that only worked on windows or other distros, that I would want to be able to include or exclude those for meteor?

Comment: I did a similar meteor project (although i used http://meteor-universal.tumblr.com/ instead). All i did was develop it to almost completion on my big machine, then transfer it over my tiny board. If you need to do checks in between, you can just comment out that dep in the packages.json

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I used meteor-universal.tumblr.com to get meteor running on the Pi. I didn't see anything on there that'll connect node.js or meteor to the GPIOs which is why I'm trying to get the npm wiring-pi installed for only the Pi.. I'll probably just comment out the items until I find another workaround